# NSViewController IBOutlet is always nil

Tags: swift, cocoa, iboutlet, nsviewcontroller, nsstackview

I have a Cocoa app that has a main `NSWindowController` and inside a `NSView` connected to a `NSViewController` object like this:

[image]

CloudCardsViewController is a `NSViewController` with its `Nib` and `IBOutlet` to a `NSStackView`. When I try to access to the outlet, app crashes and show this error on console:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2017-09-16 19:46:43.756852+0200 AppName[3402:150754] fatal error:
>   unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I add `NSViewController` by code, works fine...

Here is the code:
[image]

If I print `baseStackView` the result is `nil`

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I added the code @matt

Comment: I put `NSView` on window, after this, I drag a `NSViewController` to xib, assign a `CloudCardsViewController` and connect `NSView` to `CloudCardsViewController` view. Can I upload all the code? Thanks @matt

Comment: Where is your NSStackView in your XIB? I only see a NSView

Comment: NSStackView is on the CloudCardsViewController. Outlet points to the controller

Comment: If you want upload your code on github and i can check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you **only** load the `MainWindowController` from the XIB file. The `MainWindowController` gets initialised and with it only the connected XIB from the `CloudCardsViewontroler`. **But your `CloudCardsViewController` was never actually initialised for itself**. You cannot use your `CloudCardsViewController` like this. You need to initialise it and then add it to your `MainWindowController`.

You instantiated your class directly with the initializer. The outlets won't connect this way. The Interface Builder creates customized instances of your classes and encodes those instances into NIBs and Storyboards for repeated decoding, it doesn't define the classes themselves.

Comment: Cam you provide me an example code on github? Thanks!

Comment: Just look on every tutorial on the internet on how to use and initialise viewcontrollers